# executing cmd command with parameters

Tags: c#, cmd

I have a program that executes two **cmd** commands. The code that I use is this:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin";
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C openssl genrsa -out ProtTest.key 2048 & openssl req -new -sha256 -key ProtTest.key -out ProtTest.csr"; //if no arguments comment this line
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.Start();
```

The code works fine, but when the second command is executed the cmd window just sits and waits for the user to write some values, like email address city and so on.

My question is how to transfer those parameters as well to the cmd window?

Comment: Are you wanting to allow the user to type the email and city in directly or to provide them with your application?

Comment: If you're wanting to send them from your application, you're looking at `proc.StandardInput.Write()`.

Comment: I want the user to write  the values in to a textbox then I want to send the values to the cmd.

Comment: Is my latest answer more helpful?

Comment: Yeah it helps thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(textbox1.Text);
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(textbox2.Text);
```

This allows you to input your data as though you were running the application in the command window independantly.